# FDR correction - different number of p-values and models/hypotheses being tested

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, mixed-model, p-value, false-discovery-rate

I have $3$ predictors:

- $1$ binary (prenatal alcohol exposure)
- $1$ categorical with $4$ categories (drinking patterns e.g., light stable, heavy reducer)
- $1$ continuous (total drinks consumed during pregnancy)
- $7$ sleep outcomes

I have run $21$ linear mixed models. I want to conduct FDR correction on
my resulting $p$ values. However, because one of my predictor variables
is categorical, I have a total of $35$ $p$ values I would like to correct
for. I can't seem to find any information on how best to approach
this - should I treat it as $35$ comparisons/hypotheses, or is there a
way to have the number of $p$ values be greater than the number of
comparisons/hypotheses?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Emma.  What is the reason you have not employed a multiple regression model to relate each outcome to all three predictors simultaneously?  And since you have *two* categorical predictors, it's unclear what those $5\times 7=35$ p-values are associated with.  What are the 35 hypotheses you are testing?

Comment: Thanks for your response - the three predictors are different conceptualisations of the same exposure (prenatal alcohol exposure), one is binary, one is dose, and the final is different drinking patterns of which there are 4 (e.g., light reducer, heavy stable). The dose and patterns of exposure analyses are to further clarify and build on the findings from the binary models. I am looking at the associations between these predictors and 7 sleep outcomes. Do you have any advice on how to deal with the FDR corrections?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying a bit more. I'm wondering...what are these outcome variables? Are they related in some clear ways? Perhaps you can combine them into one scale if they have comparable items? This may require using a factor analysis based approach to determine if they are reasonable to put together, but I think you are probably testing a more core idea here rather than 21 different hypotheses or 7 outcomes. I agree with Whuber that there is no need to run a model for each IV. This is highly redundant. But it might be good to understand what the DVs are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather in your question, you are taking each predictor and running it on each outcome, thus $3$ predictors x $7$ outcomes = $21$ models. This is not necessary. I'm assuming you believe these IVs are all connected in some way with the DV. Why not run them all (your $x$ variables) into the same model the typical way:

$$
y = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + Z\gamma + \epsilon
$$

where the $Z\gamma$ is the design matrix/random effects portion of your model (which I don't see specified explicitly but is nevertheless part of the equation) and the $\epsilon$ is the leftover "noise" in predictions. As far as your $y$ here, I don't know if it is completely necessary to run so many models if your sleep outcomes here are closely related. Let's say for example we have the following sleep variables (all rated on a binary scale):

- Does your sleep get interrupted?
- Do you have difficulty waking up from alarm clocks?
- Do you require a sleep apnea mask?

These all tackle the same latent construct of "difficulty sleeping" (there are probably better ways to determine this idea, but just thinking out loud). They could be combined into a single composite and then run as a single DV. Then you would just have one model, with three predictors and one outcome, testing what is likely just one unified hypothesis. If the goal here is not hypothesis testing and instead predicting each unique outcome, perhaps my answer here would be different, but it seems you have an explanatory goal here that wouldn't be easily solved the way that you are approaching it.

Those are just my initial thoughts. Perhaps you can clarify more and I can add more to this answer. I personally don't find that testing several models at once to be useful. As [Cohen once said](https://tech.me.holycross.edu/files/2015/03/Cohen_1990.pdf), "less is more."